# Pass array of filters to a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I need to do something similar to this, where I want to determine a class from a value inside a ng-repeat inside a directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in data">
  <div class="value | classFilters[$index]">
  </div>
</div>
```

The directive must be able to support different filters for different data. So I'm thinking I want to pass one filter per value in data.

I am able to make an array of filters something like this:

```
this.$scope.classFilters = [
  this.$filter('filter1'),
  this.$filter('filter2'),
  this.$filter('filter3')
];
```

And pass that to the directive. But then I get an injector error with "Unknown provider: classFiltersFilterProvider".

Anyone have a fixed solution or an idea for an alternative solution?

Comment: Before we focus on solving how to pass a filter, what exactly are you trying do with the filter? What is `filter1`, as an example? If you are just trying to return a class name in response to a parameter, you could just do that with `ng-class="getClassNameFor($index)"`

Comment: did you try applying the filter in ng-repeat?

Comment: @New Dev yes your assumption is right.
I really want to stay with using a filter instead of a helper function like you suggest, as it is "the Angular way" of doing things. Shuhei's solution seems to kinda do both, as it calls the filter like a function. Pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use filters as functions.

```
<div ng-repeat="value in data">
  <div ng-class="classFilters[$index](value)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked like a charm. Good thinking :)